# When i Access Mongodb from the cmd using mongosh command, it returns Access Denied

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

## I intsalled MongoDB on my windows 11 computer, but when i run mongosh in my cmd it returns access denied

`>mongosh access Denied`

[this is what appears when i run the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSqCS.png)

i tried uninstalling and reinstalling and adding it to the environment variables.
`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this by enabling Compatibility mode of mongosh exe file. Check this post for detailed answer: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc/f94db755-9416-470a-9532-de9dc6ec53d2

Answer (score 0):

I realised that i dint have a mongosh file in my bin folder(user/programfiles/mongo/server/bin/), so i had to download the mongoshell. you can download it from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell). then after downloading it extract it and then go to the bin folder of the newly downloaded mongoshell and copy the path of the bin folder, then add it to the environment variaboles, restart your terminal and vwalla!